# how to add element dynamically to select list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one drop down list which contains two options, `private` and `public`. By default the selected item is `public`. On selecting the `private` option I have to go the phonebook contacts and select one of the phone numbers and after that in the selected part, that phone number and public option should be showed means it should be selected.

```
<select id="privacy" onChange="run()">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">public</option>
    <option value="2">contact</option>
</select>
```

here is the run function

```
function run() {
    var select = document.getElementById("privacy");
    var value1 = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;

    if (value1 == "contact") {
        window.location="contact.html";}
    }
```

When it goes to contact, it will select one of the phone numbers from a list. After that in selected list it should show `public, phone number` in that list as selected (value of privacy should be public, phone number);

Comment: What is the issue your having? The question is not at all clear.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan..i have one html page which contains select drop down list.in this list i am havving two option public and private.public is by default selected.when i select private option its going to phonebook n when i am selecting that phonenumber it should show me in the select drop down list like public,phonenumber.means that phonenumber should appended in that list with publi option as selected.